# assign variables before or in loops statement performance

Tags: performance, loops, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

In many programming languages, assignments are legal in loops statement like this.

```
while(variable1 = someFunction()){
...
}
```

although it would be more clear code to assign variables like this I am wondering if `someFunction` function has a computational process in it's, it would be a better way to assign variable before loops like this

```
variable1 = someFunction()
while(variable1){
...
}
```

or no matter and compilers can detect this to do not compute it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this in **Java**,**JavaScript** and **Python** that are popular languages.
in every language first I have a function that sums from number 1 to 1000.
first I assign this value before the loop and see how many second take-ups to finish, then I assign this sum in a loop condition and see the result again

**Java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        //assign variable before loop
        long startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
        int counter = sum();
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            //some code
        }
        long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("duration for assign before loop : "+(finishTime-startTime));

        //assign variable in  loop
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < sum(); i++) {
            //some code
        }
        finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("duration for assign in loop : "+(finishTime-startTime));

    }
    public static int sum(){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            sum+=i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Then write this code in javascript:

```
function sum(){
        let sum = 0;
        for (let i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            sum+=i;
        }
        return sum;
}
(function(){
        //assign variable before loop         
        let startTime= Date.now();
        let counter = sum();
        for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            //some code
        }
        let finishTime = Date.now();
        console.log("duration for assign before loop : "+(finishTime-startTime))

        //assign variable in  loop
        startTime = Date.now();
        for (let i = 0; i < sum(); i++) {
            //some code
        }
        finishTime = Date.now()
        console.log("duration for assign in loop : "+(finishTime-startTime));
})()
```

and finally, I write this code in python

```
import time

def current_milli_time():
    return int(round(time.time() * 1000))

def sum():
    sum = 0
    for i in xrange(1,1000):
        sum += i
    return sum

if __name__=="__main__":
    #assign before loop
    startTime = current_milli_time()
    counter = sum()
    for i in xrange(1,counter):
        pass
    finishTime = current_milli_time()
    print("duration for assign before loop : "+str(finishTime-startTime))

    #assign in loop
    startTime = current_milli_time()
    for i in xrange(1,sum()):
        pass
    finishTime = current_milli_time()
    print("duration for assign in loop : "+str(finishTime-startTime))
```

the result was interesting.I got this result in every language

**Java :**

duration for assign before loop : 2

duration for assign in loop : 326

**JavaScript :**

duration for assign before loop : 4

duration for assign in loop : 1846

but in **python** I got

duration for assign before the loop : 66

duration for assign in a loop : 67

as we can see in Java and JavaScript we absolutely should not use assign variable in loops if it results is the same during loop but in python, we got almost very close duration.

**Conclusion**

as a conclusion, I think it's no matter what programming language we use but it's better to don't assign variables in loops if it results remain the same during the loop